# React JS Routing issue on back button press

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have one odd requirement in one of my project, the requirement is -
1) On initial load of my web-app it should load initial page (first page).
2) If the user comes next time then he should be directly redirected to where he left previously - I'm getting the DROP STAGE from API.
3) When user comes next time then he is redirected to the previously dropped page, but on pressing back he could be redirected to the previous page of the page where he left

Now what I have done so far is -

I have used react-router-dom for routing, but the thing which happens to me is -

1) User comes first time and he is redirected to the very first page by checking the DROP stage from API
2) When user comes again, he has a DROP STAGE (from API) so I am redirecting him to the DROPPED Page.
3) When user press back button (mobile device), the user doesn't stays to the page instead he is redirected again to the DROPPED PAGE as I am checking the DROP STAGE on componentWillMount event and he is again redirected.

Workaround which I have tried are -

1) To set a localstorage variable on the dropped page and check that variable on the back button pressed page - BUT THE RESULT IS I GET THE LOCALSTORAGE VALUE AS EMPTY
2) To check the Action of page i.e. when the user press back button the action becomes POP, but the problem is when the user comes for the first time then too the action is POP - HOW CAN I GET THE ACTION AS PUSH ON INITIAL LOAD

How can I achieve my functionality. Please help

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a module which will be called only once when the application is loaded but it should be loaded irrespective of which ever page the user accesses first.
What you can do is add an empty component in your main router file which should be the first to be called and is called in all the routes. And in the componentDidMount of the component, you should handle the redirection no where else. So the redirection will happen only once thus handling the back actions automatically.

Comment: Please accept it as answer if you find this as a solution for the stack overflow community and upvote if you find it useful